# How to submit the value in an inputtext field by setting autoSubmit to false

Tags: validation, oracle-adf

I have an ADF form based on a VO and I need to check whether a particular field is null or not on click of a Submit button. For this, i set autoSubmit to true and get the value entered to a variable in my bean.On click of Submit button , i check if the variable is null or not and display error faces message if the variable is null. But how do i get the value entered in the form to a variable in the bean with autoSubmit set to false?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have it turned on in the first place? And why do you want to turn it off? Are you clear on it's functioning and why to use it?

Autosubmit is used to support Partial-Page Refresh.
If you don't need PPR, Just turn it off. The value will still be available once the submit button is pressed. Read about it [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/partial-submit-vs-auto-submit).

> An input component that has its autosubmit property set to true also
>   performs a partial submit of the form. However, this time it doesn't
>   submit the entire form but only the component that triggers the submit
>   plus components referenced it in their PartialTriggers property.

Autosubmit is not required to access values entered into input components on the screen. Autosubmit submits only the field and also bypasses certain phases of the page processing lifecycle.
if you turn autosubmit off, the entire page - all the fields - is submitted and goes through the complete page processing lifecycle, so you have access to all input fields.
Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/b31973/af_lifecycle.htm#ADFUI9861).